# How to find list of all functions bind to a particular hook from my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

I want to remove all actions attached to admin_notice hook in my plugin at the time a user updates the plugin. Is there any way to find the list of functions attached to admin_notice hook by my plugin?

Comment: if you work with Linux, there is the command `grep -r admin_notice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Plugin ! It supports following features for Hooks

- Shows all hooks fired on the current request, along with hooked actions, their priorities, and their components
- Filter hooks by part of their name
- Filter actions by component (WordPress core, Plugin X, Plugin Y, theme)

https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor